# Is there a way to save a 3D volume to a single DICOM file in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pydicom

I'm processing a 3D numpy array and would like to know if it is possible to write/read the entire 3D volume as 1 single 3D .dcm rather than a series of 2D .dcm files. Can this be accomplished using pydicom library as this is what I'm using. I'm new in working with DICOMs so I'm not sure how to go about about implementing this if possible.

I found this to be what I wanted but I could not access the code as the link to it is dead. https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/issues/786

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on what you intended the SOP Class to be for your output dataset, please edit your question to add this information

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55531642/2878353